# Slide a div in from off screen and then back on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to move a div in from off screen and then back on toggle

```
$('a.show').on('click',function() {
if($('#left-navi-designers').css('left')=='0px'){
    $('#left-navi-designers').animate({left: '-100%'}, 1000);        
}else{
    $('#left-navi-designers').animate({left:0}, 1000); 
}
});
```

That is what i have for the JavaScript. I have this for my CSS:

```
#left-navi-designers {
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
background: #fff;
width: 100%;
left: -100%;
 }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="left-icons"><a class="show" style="color:#999;">DUH!</a></div>
<div id="left-navi-designers">
 <div id="topNavigation">
<ul class="topLevelNavigation">
<a href=".topLevelNavigation" class="button"><li>DESIGNERS</li></a>
<a href=".topLevelNavigation2" class="button"><li>EMERGING</li></a>
<a href=".topLevelNavigation3" class="button"><li>STUDIOS</li></a>
<a href=".topLevelNavigation4" class="button"><li>NEW FACES</li></a>
<a href=".topLevelNavigation5" class="button"><li>EDITORS</li></a>
<a href="#box1" class="button"><li>MEDIA KIT</li></a>
<a href="#box1" class="button"><li>BEAUTY</li></a>
<a href="#box1" class="button"><li>BRANDS</li></a>
<a href="#box1" class="button"><li>MODELS</li></a>
<a href="#box1" class="button"><li>PARTIES</li></a>
 </ul></div>
```

I'm very new to this and am just trying to get some things figured out. Here is the site i am playing on http://keithfrenchdesigns.com/RunwayMag/designers_main.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the problem is? works fine if I copy/paste your code like here http://jsfiddle.net/wm3c4/

Comment: I just tried it and it works http://jsfiddle.net/dJyFM/ Make sure you're loading your scripts and jQuery correctly.

Comment: It must be the jQuery loading issue. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

you also can toggle your div with a css transition. This is more quick because you only have to toggle a class. See my example jsfiddle to see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Wkgf/1/

**jquery**

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#slider').toggleClass('open');

})
```

**css**

```
#slider{
    background:blue;
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    position:relative;
    left:-520px;  
}
.open{
    left:0px !important;
}
.transition{

  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
     -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
       -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
          transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */

}
```

**html**

```
<button>slide</button>
<div id="slider" class="transition"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works and I see you have included jQuery UI, so instead using `animate` and negative `left`, you can use visibility and [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) with animation:

> Display or hide the matched elements.

Code:

```
$('a.show').on('click', function () {
    $('#left-navi-designers').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/r7m3C/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this functions.

```
function SlideIn(el){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transition = "left 1.5s linear 0s";
    elem.style.left = "10px";
}
function SlideOut(el){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transition = "left 1.5s linear 0s";
    elem.style.left = "-200px";
}

// Use this buttons, for example.
<button onclick="SlideIn('box1')">Slide in</button>
<button onclick="SlideOut('box1')">Slide out</button>

<div id="box1">Put something in here</div>
```

This is just an example, try it at your own boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code like here http://jsfiddle.net/wm3c4/. And it works just fine the only problem I see is in your page you have this:

```
$('a.show').on('click',function() {
    if($('#website').css('left')=='0px'){
        $('#website').animate({left: '-100%'}, 1000);        
    }else{
        $('#website').animate({left:0}, 1000); 
    }
});
```

But there is no element with `id="website"`. Try to change that selector to the one you post here.